# Why does the solution for CCA always lie in the span of the data?

Tags: optimization, machine-learning

Assume you have the following optimization problem, which is exactly the optimization problem for canocial correlation analysis:

$$arg \max_{w_x, w_y} w_x^T C_{xy} w_y$$
s.t.
$$w_x^T C_{xx} w_x = 1$$
$$w_y^T C_{yy} w_y = 1$$
where $C_{xx} = XX^T$, $C_{yy} = YY^T$, $C_{xy} = XY^T$,
and $X \in \mathbb{R}^{d_1 \times N}$, $Y \in \mathbb{R}^{d_2 \times N}$.

I want to show that there is always an optimal solution that lies in the span of the data, i.e. $w_x = X \alpha_x, w_y = Y \alpha_y$, $\alpha_x,\alpha_y \in \mathbb{R}^{N}$.

To do this, I tried to show that any optimal solution $w_x^T$ can be replaced by a vector $w_x' = X \alpha_x$. However, I failed to find out a formula for the coefficients, so I am starting to doubt this is the right approach.

How can I show that the solution always lies in the span of the data?

Answer (score 1):

Assume $w_x$ and $w_y$ can be rewritten as the sum of two vectors. One lies in the span of the data and the other is orthogonal to the data, i.e.,

$$ w_x = X \alpha_x + n_x \\  w_x = X \alpha_y + n_y \, ,$$

where $n_x, n_y \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Let us use the following notation $s_x := X \alpha_x$ and $s_y := X \alpha_y$. The maximization problem now reads

$$ \text{argmax} \ (s_x + n_x)^T C_{xy} (s_y + n_y) \\ 
\text{s.t} \ (s_x + n_x)^T C_{xx} (s_x + n_x) = 1 \\
(s_y + n_y)^T C_{yy} (s_y + n_y) = 1 \, .$$

If we expand the objective function, we obtain

$$ (s_x + n_x)^T C_{xy} (s_y + n_y) \\ 
= s_x^T C_{xy} s_y + s_x^T C_{xy} n_y \\ + n_x^T C_{xy} s_y + n_x^T C_{xy} n_y \, .$$

Since $n_x$ and $n_y$ are orthogonal to $X$ and $Y$ respectively, the above equation becomes

$$ (s_x + n_x)^T C_{xy} (s_y + n_y) = s_x^T C_{xy} s_y \, .$$

Thus, the solution $w_x$,$w_y$ of your shown optimization problem lies in the span of the data.